# Is there any TeX (or LaTeX) package capable of rot13-encoding an ASCII text?

Tags: rotating, input-encodings, fun

This might be a nice thing to obfuscate answers to quizzes (better than `\rotatebox[c]{180}{...}`).  (I understand that this is trivial using LuaTeX, but I'd be interested in a generic TeX solution.  Most probably I could write one myself - it's not *that* difficult - but being a bit lazy, I don't want to reinvent the wheel.)

Comment: If you wanted to obliterate, rather then encode the answer, you could look at the `censor` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is: the [`rotchiffre`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotchiffre) package by Heiko Oberdiek.